# Creating dynamic block in azurerm_api_management_api terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create APIs with certain inputs dynamically into an APIM instance in azure. For that I have created a resource azurerm_api_management_api, to which I am going to pass the values like name, version, display name dynamically from a local.tf file. But when I tried, the error was

```
Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on api-management\api_management_api.tf line 6, in resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "apim_api":
│    6:   dynamic apiValues{
│
│ Blocks of type "apiValues" are not expected here.
```

Here is the resource block.

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "apim_api" {
    revision            = "1"
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name

  dynamic apiValues{
    for_each = local.apiDetails
    content{
        name                = apiValues.value.name
        display_name        = apiValues.value.display_name
        path                = ""
        protocols           = ["http","https"]
        service_url         = "http://spring-boot-redis.azurewebsites.net"
        import {
            content_format = "openapi-link"
            content_value  = "./SpringBootRedis.yaml"
  }
    }
  }
}
```

### locals.tf

```
locals {
  apiDetails = [
    {
      name = "spring-boot-redis"
      display_name = "Spring Boot Redis"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve this? As I am planning to put this on an azure pipeline. So that I have to only take care of the API specification and names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure why you are attempting to use a dynamic block for a block that does not exist according to the documentation. The error message agrees the block does not exist in the resource schema.

It appears what you are trying to achieve here is multiple resources with a value from a `local.apiDetails`:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "apim_api" {
  for_each = local.apiDetails

  revision            = "1"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name

  name                = each.value.name
  display_name        = each.value.display_name
  path                = ""
  protocols           = ["http","https"]
  service_url         = "http://spring-boot-redis.azurewebsites.net"
  import {
    content_format = "openapi-link"
    content_value  = "./SpringBootRedis.yaml"
  }
}
```

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) has more information.

Comment: I am trying to on board different APIs onto APIM. And I have the OpenAPI specification for that. This has to be a continue process. So attempted the dynamic block. But looked like it didn't have support for this resource.

Comment: @SatyaPanigrahy Yes my answer does that.

Comment: It worked finally. I did a little change to the local variable. I had to use mapping object instead of a tuple. Thanks!